# Why is a default constructor required when storing in a map?

Tags: c++, constructor

I'm getting the error:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'A::A()'
note: candidates are: A::A(const A&)
note:                 A::A(const std::string&, size_t)
```

From this:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>

using std::map;
using std::string;

class A {
public:
    string path;
    size_t size;
    A (const string& p, size_t s) : path(p), size(s) { }
    A (const A& f) : path(f.path), size(f.size) { }
    A& operator=(const A& rhs) {
        path = rhs.path;
        size = rhs.size;
        return *this;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    map<string, A> mymap;

    A a("world", 1);
    mymap["hello"] = a;      // <----- here
    A b(mymap["hello"]);     // <----- and here
}
```

Please tell me why the code wants a constructor with no parameters.

Comment: If creating a default constructor is not meaningful, use `insert` and `find`: `mymap.insert(a);` and `auto iter = mymap.find("hello"); if (iter != mymap.end()) { A b(*iter); }`.

Comment: Thanks. In my case it is indeed not meaningful.

Comment: when the default constructor meaningfulness, you might want this:  `auto it = mymap.insert(mymap.begin(), std::pair<string, A>("hello", a));`. after that point, `it->first` is `"hello"`, and  `it->second` is either `a`, if there wasn't  previously an element for `"hello"`, or  `it->second` is the previous element for the key `"hello"` (and `a` isn't inserted).    That behaviour has the same semantics of `mymap["hello"]` if you could tell it to use the constructor you used to construct  `a` instead of the default constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mymap["hello"]` can attempt to create a value-initialized `A`, so a default constructor is required.

If you're using a type `T` as a `map` value (and plan to access value via `operator[]`), it needs to be default-constructible - i.e. **you need a parameter-less (default) constructor**. `operator[]` on a map will value-initialize the mapped value if a value with the key provided is not found.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf "and plan to access value via operator[]" seems pretty plain to me

Comment: @M.M. Because you know the correct answer. It doesn't belong in a parenthesis, it is the main and only issue.

Answer (score 7):

Because `map` requires *DefaultConstructible* values, since when using subscript operator and the key is not found it adds it mapped to a default constructed value.

Comment: More specifically, operator[] will *create* a new "default constructed" item when you attempt to add an item that does not exist then return a *reference* to that item that gets assigned whatever value you want.

Comment: In C++11 does this still hold over the entire map? Since the requirements were put per-operation, it must be only that `operator[]` has this requirement. (`insert` would have no need for it, for example.)

Comment: @GManNickG: `operator[]` requires _DefaultInsertable_, not the entire map. I thought this was the case in _C++03_ as well...

Comment: **−1** “Because `map` requires *DefaultConstructible* values” is incorrect as of C++11 and later.

Answer (score 4):

In general a default constructor is **not** required for a `map` item value.

It was required in C++03, but that requirement was dropped in C++11, which often instead of posing container-wide requirements uses a more fine grained requirement scheme with requirements on the use of particular member functions.

The `map::operator[]` is one such member function, because it will create an item with the given key and a default-constructed value, if an item with the key doesn't exist.

This is also the reason why there isn't a `const` version of `map::operator[]`: it potentially modifies the map.

In C++11 and later you can use the `at` accessor to access an item with a given key in a `const` map, without the verbosity & complexity of a `find`.

Since `map::at` doesn't attempt to create an item, it doesn't require the item type to be default constructible.

And so one practical solution for your problem is to use `map::at` instead of `map::operator[]`.

Comment: Just to clarify. i actually gave it a try: If the OP would modify his last lines into: `mymap.insert(std::make_pair("hello", a));`
and `A b(mymap.at("hello"));`,
all would be fine. (And would compile with C++11)

Answer (score 1):

Long time without using C++, but If I recall correctly if you don't define a constructor for a class the compiler will create a paramless one for you. As soon as you define a constructor with parameters the compiler won't create a paramless one for you, so, you are required to create one. This added to what K-ballo exposed leads to your errors.