# Why can the compiler not detect the constructor?

Tags: c++, ios, xcode

I have this class:

```
class FileRatio{
public:
    double x;
    double y;

    FileRatio(double xx,double yy){
        this->x = xx;
        this->y = yy;
    }
};
```

When I choose "build", XCode is able to build it. When I choose "run", then I get a "build failed" message:

> No matching constructor for initialisation of FileRatio

What is the problem ?

**EDIT:** I try to use it in the following ways:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, FileRatio>fileRatioMap;
std::vector<std::string> tokens = split(line, ',');

FileRatio fileRatio = FileRatio(stod(tokens[1]),stod(tokens[2]));
fileRatioMap[tokens[0]] = fileRatio;
```

And later I do:

```
 FileRatio ratio = fileRatioMap[name];
```

**EDIT:** The compiler does not highlight a specific line in MY code. Instead, it appears in some class called "memory" which is part of Xcode's toolchain.

EDIT:

The whole error message is:

> No matching constructor for initialisation of FileRatio

The line that is highlighted is:

```
construct(_Up* __p, _Args&&... __args)
{
  ::new((void*)__p) _Up(_VSTD::forward<_Args>(__args)...);
}
```

Comment: How are you trying to use it?

Comment: @BobTFish I updated the question

Comment: Thanks. At a quick glance, your usage is reasonable. Could you please include the whole error message, showing where it claims there is an error (in `memory`, whatever that is).

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14164223/why-is-a-default-constructor-required-when-storing-in-a-map). In short, you probably need a default constructor...

Comment: @dandan78 +1. Also to add to that comment. It might be of use to use pointers instead, that way you don't need a default constructor and can detect if no such entry exists by checking if it returns null.

Comment: @Neijwiert can you explain where should I use pointers ? It doesn't seem obvious to me..

Comment: `std::unordered_map<std::string, FileRatio *> fileRatioMap;`. Use `new` and `delete` operator to insert/get/remove entries.

Comment: Even better would be to avoid using `[]` operator altogether and use `unordered_map::find` instead. Also I would recommend implementing the move contructor and operator. Would avoid unnecessary  copies. Altough no heavy-weight allocating is going on, it is a good practice in c++11